# Use 3D Touch action with Touch ID protected device

Tags: swift, 3d, touch, quickaction

Hi guys I've a big question.
If I have an app that could be protected by Touch ID protection, how do I have to manage the 3D Touch quick action that interests data? I've to ask fingerprint before the execution of the action, or I let the action be executed without any lock, or maybe I create an alert that tell the user 'Impossible to use quick action while Touch ID protection is actived' ?
So, I ask you the best way to manage this type of problem..code will be well accepted :)

Comment: it should be like when the app opens the app should ask for Touch ID. Unless it is successful the screen shouldn't work. You can't stop 3D Touch actions before.

Comment: So..how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It should be noted that
>   sensitive information are not to be shown when the app icon is 3D
>   touched.
>
> What should happen is that you should allow the user to interact with
>   the 3D Touch but when the app opens the screen based on user's
>   selection, the app should prompt for Touch ID or passcode alert. 
>   Unless it's verified app shouldn't function as intended since the user
>   is not authenticated at that point.
>
> **In case you want to stop the actions from appearing all together, then it could be done, you would
>   just need to change the 3D Touch actions dynamically.**

**Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34108818/2570153) for details, there are two ways to generate action 3D Touch action items, static and dynamic. Using the dynamic one, you could achieve it.**

Comment: Well..in my cases, I want simply add a name with the price of something I bought..so I don't need any view to appear, only an alert to compile..but You are telling me that i can't stop it..so i cannot implement rapid purchase from the app icon

Comment: 3D Touch action are not something that happen in background, what happens in that your app opens and a particular screen/view controller does the action based on your 3D Touch. So accordingly, the 3D Touch action could trigger a purchase action in your case but that action would be happening in the app on some view controller, it won't be in background, your app will in any case open up to perform that action.

Comment: In case you want to stop the action then it could be done, you would just need to change the 3D Touch actions dynamically.
Refer this for details https://stackoverflow.com/q/34108818/2570153

Comment: @MettDich did it help?