# disabling/enabling icons on 3D Touch. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I'm trying to implement a 3D Touch. Basically I have 4 icons showing after hard press on the app's icon. Each touch works as it should and runs a specific action. However, I would like to disable some icons after the other was pressed (action was run). How can I do it? All icon files etc. I had implemented in info.plist. Is there a way to write them all by code?

Comment: It's possible, take a look on this post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108818/ios-dynamically-edit-3d-touch-shortcut-list

Comment: thanks, it helped!